# Which one outperforms: lots of inserts OR UNION ALL? SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

What's better to use:

```
INSERT #tableN (ID,NAME,Value) 
  SELECT 1, 'a', SUM(a) FROM tab UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'b', SUM(b) FROM tab UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'c', SUM(c) FROM tab UNION ALL 
  SELECT 4, 'd', SUM(d) FROM tab UNION ALL 
  SELECT 5, 'e', SUM(e) FROM tab UNION ALL 
  ...
  SELECT 3000, 'a3000', SUM(a3001) FROM tab UNION ALL 
  SELECT 3001, 'a3001', SUM(a3001) FROM tab
```

or

```
INSERT #tableN (ID,NAME,Value) 
  SELECT 1 , 'a', SUM(a)
  FROM tab

INSERT #tableN (ID,NAME,Value) 
  SELECT 2, 'b', SUM(b)
  FROM tab

INSERT #tableN (ID,NAME,Value) 
  SELECT 3, 'c', SUM(c)
  FROM tab

INSERT #tableN (ID,NAME,Value) 
  SELECT 4, 'd', SUM(d)
  FROM tab
...
INSERT #tableN (ID,NAME,Value) 
  SELECT 3001, 'a30001', SUM(a3001)
  FROM tab
```

Comment: Performance wise multiple inserts are better than union all. I tried inserting around 3500 records using both approaches and multiple insert was much more faster than Union All

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you're wanting to rotate the table to create a new table. There are tidier ways to do this than writing (or generating) all that SQL. Look into PIVOT and [UNPIVOT](http://texastoo.com/post/2008/12/02/TSQL-UNPIVOT.aspx) especially. It allows you to convert the columns into rows, and provide filtering on the intermediate result set. You may need to find some more resources in relation to pivoting, but the link above should jump start you well enough if you decide to consider this option.

Comment: Josh, link to UNPIVOT is dead.

Answer (score 3):

@Josh has the right answer for your case, but if you were wondering if multiple `INSERT`s or one `INSERT` with a `UNION ALL`, the single `INSERT` with `UNION ALL` is faster when you are inserting a lot of data.

From comments on [this post](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/08/sql-server-insert-multiple-records-using-one-insert-statement-use-of-union-all/):

```
I try to execute 400 insert statements to table about 20 columns (int or float). Regarding performance there is MUCH difference. ;)

INSERT statements way: about 5 seconds
INSERT SELECT UNION ALL way: 40 miliseconds!!!
```

Comment: That blog post is flawed though. They should have tried doing all the single statement inserts in a single transaction to give a meaningful comparison.